Reconstructing a Lie group from its Maurer-Cartan form (role of completeness)
Theorem III.8.7 in Sharpe and Chern's "Differential Geometry: Cartan's Generalization of Klein's Erlangen Program" states:

If $M$ is a simply connected manifold, $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra, and $\omega\in\Omega^1(M,\mathfrak{g})$ is such that

$\mathrm{d} \omega+\frac12[\omega,\omega]=0$;
$\omega_x:T_xM\to \mathfrak{g}$ is an isomorphism for each $x\in M$;
$\omega$ is complete (i.e. each constant vector field is complete),

then $M$, with any choice of identity, has a unique Lie group structure whose Maurer-Cartan form is $\omega$.

My issue is with the proof: it never explicitly uses $\omega$'s completeness. In fact, it cites a "Fundamental Theorem" that doesn't directly apply:
Fundamental Theorem:

If $(M,x_0)$ is simply connected, $G$ is a Lie group with Maurer-Cartan form $\theta_G$, and $\eta\in \Omega^1(M,\mathfrak{g})$ satisfies the structure equation $\mathrm{d}\eta+\frac12[\eta,\eta]=0$, then for any $g\in G$ there is a unique smooth map $f:M\to G$ such that $f(x_0)=g$ and its logarithmic derivative $\delta f:=f^\ast\theta_G$ coincides with $\eta$.

The idea is to construct maps $m:M\times M\to M$ and $i:M\to M$ that act as the multiplication and inversion map. For that, they construct $1$-forms $\eta$ that are expressed in terms of $\omega$ the same way log-derivatives of a multiplication or an inversion map would be in terms of the MC form, and then check that $\mathrm{d}\eta+\frac12[\eta,\eta]=0$. Then they cite the Fundamental Theorem to reconstruct two unique maps $m:M\times M\to M$ and $i:M\to M$. However, the Fundamental Theorem obviously doesn't apply because the target manifold, $M$, isn't a Lie group yet.
This seems to be the place where completeness should come in. I suppose one needs to show that the Fundamental Theorem holds not just for Lie group targets, but for all targets with a $1$-form $\omega$ that satisfies all 3 conditions above. The book skips over this part, proving that the Maurer-Cartan form can be developed along any path before they even discuss the concept of completeness.
Does anyone have intuition for what is necessary to complete the proof?

Sharpe is the only author of the cited book.  Chern is not an author.

@DmitriPavlov ah, indeed, just foreword.

You correctly pointed out that the fundamental theorem should be generalized in the way you described.  Completeness is necessary to prove the analogous generalization of Theorem 7.1.  The second paragraph of its proof implicitly uses the fact that there is a unique primitive taking the given value at some fixed point in the interval.  The analogous statement for arbitrary M uses the completeness property of the 1-form precisely at this point.

@DmitriPavlov do you know how to show the existence of a unique primitive? On Lie groups, I can just take a finite number of local primitives and stitch them together by translating their values. But without a group structure it seems like I would need to show that any automorphism of $(G,\omega)$ is uniquely determined by its value at one point. And I'm not sure how to do that.

@DmitriPavlov oh, is the argument for developments simply that $\omega^{-1}(\eta(\dot\gamma(t)))$ is a time-dependent vector field, which at every $t$ is complete, and hence is complete itself? I'm not sure if such a theorem for flows of time-dependent vector fields actually holds though.

A quick and dirty proof of the existence of flows for nonconstant vector fields can be given as follows.  Since the exponential map is a local diffeomorphism in any Lie group G, every smooth path in G can be homotoped to a piecewise smooth path whose Darboux derivative is piecewise constant.  Therefore, every Lie algebra-valued differential 1-form can be homotoped to a piecewise constant Lie algebra-valued differential 1-form via a flat homotopy (i.e., with a vanishing Maurer–Cartan form).

By making the subdivision sufficiently small, we can ensure the homotopy moves points at most by some ε>0.  Now working with an arbitrary manifold M equipped with a Lie-algebra-valued 1-form ω such that dω+[ω∧ω]=0, using compactness of the interval [a,b], we ensure the development of the piecewise-constant approximation to ω exists in M (by assumption), and, furthermore, the flat homotopy lifts to M (here we make ε>0 small enough).  Therefore, the development of the original path exists.

G is a Lie group (by definition).  The manifold M is not a Lie group (yet).

@DmitriPavlov it seems that we need the proof of the existence of piecewise-constant approximations to also hold on M. That should work, because the analog of the exponential map exists here too, and is a diffeomorphism by the same argument as in Lie groups.

What is being approximated is the differential 1-form on [a,b] with values in the Lie algebra, which does not involve M.  The manifold M gets involved only at the last stage, when we choose ε>0 so that the developed homotopy stays inside M.  The developed homotopy always exists locally on [a,b] (as already proved in the book), and the global extension (for sufficiently small ε>0) is possible because [a,b] is compact.

when you say "lift to $M$", are you using some local diffeomorphism between $G$ and $M$ given by something like $\exp\circ\omega$? I guess I'm wondering why I can't do without $G$. I think I can define a local exponential map on $M$ and use that to deform paths to turn them into piecewise integral curves of constant vector fields via a flat homotopy. Wouldn't that be enough?

These are local liftings, whose existence is established by (the generalization of) Theorem 6.1.  Alternatively, you can use local liftings to define a local exponential map, like you proposed.  Both choices work fine.

@DmitriPavlov Got it, thanks a lot!

On $M\times G$, the Pfaffian system $\omega-g^{-1}dg$ arises from a foliation, by the Frobenius theorem.  Let $\tilde{M}$ be a leaf, i.e. a maximal integral manifold of the foliation, through some point $(m_0,1)\in M\times G$. The constant vector fields then live on $\tilde{M}$, pulled back from both local diffeomorphisms to $M$ and to $G$, since locally $\tilde{M}$ is the graph of a local diffeomorphism matching the Maurer-Cartan forms, so matching the constant vector fields. By a theorem of Ehressman (Theorem B.2 in my Introduction to Cartan geometries, but the proof is very easy), the completeness of the vector fields ensures that both $\tilde{M}\to M$ and $\tilde{M}\to G$ are covering maps. This is where the completeness is needed: a local diffeomorphism matching up complete vector fields on connected manifolds is a covering map.
Every connected covering space of a connected Lie group is a Lie group for a unique Lie group structure for which the covering map is a local isomorphism of Lie groups. I think you can find the proof of that statement in many textbooks on Lie groups. The covering map $\tilde{M}\to G$ makes $\tilde{M}$ a Lie group. The covering map $\tilde{M}\to M$ is a diffeomorphism, because $M$ is connected and simply connected.

That's a cool proof, although I'm a bit perplexed as to why Sharpe didn't include it (the Ehresmann theorem is already in the book!). Nevertheless, the proof via developments also seems quite valuable.

@AlexBogatskiy: I agree that the proof by developments is valuable. I am ashamed that even after reading Sharpe's book (when I was his master's student), I wrote a paper proving Ehresmann's theorem, without noticing that it was already known.

By the Frobenius theorem, the developments lie on the leaves. We can look at the developments as just lifting each curve in $M$ by the covering map $\tilde{M}\to M$, then mapping each point of that lifted curve by $\tilde{M}\to G$.

ah, of course. Thank you! I have yet to understand developments in more general Cartan geometries, so this is a very nice prototype.

The latest draft of my Introduction to Cartan geometries (https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.14457) gives the proof I gave above, with much more detail.

amazing, thanks Ben.
